# Sum values of a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Given an Object of this structure

```
{
    "1": {
        "data": {
            "a": 100,
            "z": 100,
            "e": 50
        },
        "percentage": {
            "a": 10,
            "z": 10,
            "e": 41.09
        }
    },
    "2": {
        "data": {
            "a": 10,
            "z": 10,
            "e": 20
        },
        "percentage": {
            "a": 30,
            "z": 40,
            "e": 50
        }
    }
}
```

i want to sum the values of this object in order to get this similar structure

```
{
    "data": {
        "a": sum(a),
        "z": sum(z),
        "e": sum(e)
    },
    "percentage": {
        "a": sum(a)/numberOfelements,
        "z": sum(z)/numberOfelements,
        "e": sum(e)/numberOfelements
    }
}
```

As am just started learnig js i find it hard to implement the sum inside this map

```
Object.keys(filtered).map(key => ({
        data: data[key].data,
        percentage: data[key].percentage,
      }))
```

any help would be appriciated

Comment: What is the significance of the "percentage" structures in the original object?  Do you ignore them to create the output?

Comment: what do mean by numberOfelements? are they elements in the original object or the data object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If numOfElemements meant elements in data object, then current implementation will do. Else uncomment the existing commented lines, and comment the line after the last commented line. Which considers elements in the data object.

```js
const obj = {
  1: {
    data: {
      a: 100,
      z: 100,
      e: 50,
    },
  },
  2: {
    data: {
      a: 10,
      z: 10,
      e: 20,
    },
  },
};
function groupBySum(obj) {
  let data = {};
  let percentage = {};
  // let numberOfElements = 0;
  for (let i in obj) {
    // numberOfElements += 1;
    for (let j in obj[i].data) {
      if (data[j] === undefined) {
        data[j] = obj[i].data[j];
      } else {
        data[j] += obj[i].data[j];
      }
    }
  }
  for (let i in data) {
    // percentage[i] = data[i] / numberOfElements;
    percentage[i] = data[i] / Object.keys(data).length;
  }
  return {
    data,
    percentage,
  };
}
console.log(groupBySum(obj));
```

Also it'll be a good idea to change your current structure to array format as below.

```
const obj = [
  {
    data: {
      a: 100,
      z: 100,
      e: 50,
    },
    percentage: {
      a: 10,
      z: 10,
      e: 41.09,
    },
  },
  {
    data: {
      a: 10,
      z: 10,
      e: 20,
    },
    percentage: {
      a: 30,
      z: 40,
      e: 50,
    },
  },
];
```